# Hashmap not working for retrieving roles back for a user. JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm trying to make a mute command for a discord bot where it removes all the user's roles and gives them the Muted Role and then after a certain amount of time it gives them their old roles back. I am trying to use a Hashmap to store the player's roles and then give it back but it seems to not work. If anyone here could help I would be really thankful. Here is my code:

```
    public static HashMap<List, Role> roleMap = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {

    String command = event.getName();
        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("mute")) {
            Member user = event.getOption("user").getAsMember();
            roleMap.put(event.getOption("user").getAsMember().getRoles(), event.getGuild().getRoleById(id));
            event.getGuild().modifyMemberRoles(event.getOption("user").getAsMember(), event.getGuild().getRoleById(id)).queue();
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getOption("user").getAsUser().getAsMention() + " has been muted").queue();
            if (!event.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.MANAGE_ROLES)) {
                event.reply("You do not have the required permissions to use this command!").setEphemeral(true).queue();
            }
            new java.util.Timer().schedule(

                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            event.getGuild().removeRoleFromMember(event.getOption("user").getAsUser(), event.getGuild().getRoleById("id")).queue();
                            event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(event.getOption("user").getAsUser(), roleMap.get(event.getOption("user").getAsMember().getRoles()));
                        }
                    },
                    event.getOption("duration").getAsLong() * 1000
            );
        }
}
```

Comment: Unless you are completely certain that each role list will never change, you cannot use that List as a Map key.  From [the documentation of Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html): “Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.”

Comment: The role list would eventually change, is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Do you even need the Map?  Why not just store the Role in a local variable instead of storing it a Map, then use that variable in your TimerTask?  (By the way, all of those calls to event.getOption("user") make the code much harder to read.  You should call event.getOption("user") only once and place the result in a variable, then call getAsUser() and getAsMember() only once each and place those values in variables.)

Comment: I have added the variable: List roles = event.getOption("user").getAsMember().getRoles();
And I have added to the timer task:                    event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(event.getOption("user").getAsUser(), (Role) roles).queue(); 
But I am getting this error now: 
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Role
 at slashcommands.MuteCommand$1.run(MuteCommand.java:38)
 at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
 at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Comment: Obviously you cannot cast a List of roles to a single Role object.  (If the List contains multiple elements, which Role would you expect the statement to use?)  Write a loop that calls addRoleToMember in its body.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i<=15; i++) {
                                    event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(event.getOption("user").getAsUser(), (Role) roles).queue(); }

It still shows the same error, it removes the users roles and gives him the Muted Role but doesn't give it back.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm bothering you with these questions, but it's been a while since I wrote java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let’s make this more readable.  You are calling `event.getOption("user")` in seven different places, which makes the code hard to read.  So let’s just call it once:

```
Guild guild = event.getGuild();

OptionMapping userOption = event.getOption("user");
User user = userOption.getAsUser();
Member member = userOption.getAsMember();
```

Now we can clean things up considerably:

```
@Override
public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {

    String command = event.getName();
    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("mute")) {
        Guild guild = event.getGuild();

        OptionMapping userOption = event.getOption("user");
        User user = userOption.getAsUser();
        Member member = userOption.getAsMember();

        if (!event.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.MANAGE_ROLES)) {
            event.reply("You do not have the required permissions to use this command!").setEphemeral(true).queue();
            return;
        }

        Iterable<Role> oldRoles = member.getRoles();
        Role mutedRole = guild.getRoleById(id);

        guild.modifyMemberRoles(member, mutedRole).queue();
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(
            user.getAsMention() + " has been muted").queue();

        new java.util.Timer().schedule(
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    guild.removeRoleFromMember(user, mutedRole).queue();
                    for (Role role : oldRoles) {
                        guild.addRoleToMember(user, role));
                    }
                }
            },
            event.getOption("duration").getAsLong() * 1000
        );
    }
}
```

Notice that the permission check should be the first step performed.  There is no reason to continue with any other logic if the user doesn’t have permission to execute the command.

Also notice the use of `for (Role role : oldRoles)` to re-add the roles one by one.

You should not make multiple Timers.  Just create one Timer, and keep it in a private field:

```
private final java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

@Override
public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
```

And then, of course, use it in your method:

```
timer.schedule(
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
```

So the final version looks like this:

```
private final java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

@Override
public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {

    String command = event.getName();
    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("mute")) {
        Guild guild = event.getGuild();

        OptionMapping userOption = event.getOption("user");
        User user = userOption.getAsUser();
        Member member = userOption.getAsMember();

        if (!event.getMember().hasPermission(Permission.MANAGE_ROLES)) {
            event.reply("You do not have the required permissions to use this command!").setEphemeral(true).queue();
            return;
        }

        Iterable<Role> oldRoles = member.getRoles();
        Role mutedRole = guild.getRoleById(id);

        guild.modifyMemberRoles(member, mutedRole).queue();
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(
            user.getAsMention() + " has been muted").queue();

        timer.schedule(
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    guild.removeRoleFromMember(user, mutedRole).queue();
                    for (Role role : oldRoles) {
                        guild.addRoleToMember(user, role));
                    }
                }
            },
            event.getOption("duration").getAsLong() * 1000
        );
    }
}
```

Your code is using `guild.getRoleById(id)` to obtain the “muted” role.  I assume you have set `id` elsewhere in your class and it does in fact refer to a special role intended for muted users.

Disclaimer:  I have never done Discord programming, and I have no way to test any of the above code.  I mainly based this on [the SlashCommandInteractionEvent documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/interaction/command/SlashCommandInteractionEvent.html).

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, this really helped me with knowledge and my bot. Appreciate it. Have a good one!